# binwalk cannot find gzip sections

Tags: binary-analysis, decompress

I am starring at the following [exe](http://incenter.medical.philips.com/doclib/getdoc.aspx?func=ll&objid=9792178&objaction=download) file, see main page [here](http://clinical.netforum.healthcare.philips.com/global/Explore/Clinical-News/MRI/Philips-DICOM-Viewer-download-version-R30-SP3). It seems pretty clear (using -E entropy option) that the exe contains compressed section. For some reason `binwalk` is not capable of finding the start of those sections.

Here is what I have:

```
$ binwalk -v -B PmsDView.exe 

Scan Time:     2016-09-22 14:42:04
Target File:   /tmp/PmsDView.exe
MD5 Checksum:  911d92675f559a40400f7ca2b69c8544
Signatures:    344

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Microsoft executable, portable (PE)
2015          0x7DF           Copyright string: "Copyright 1995-2005 Mark Adler "
```

However it seems like they are using `gzip`:

```
$ hexdump -C PmsDView.exe
000007a0  30 00 30 00 31 00 35 00  00 00 00 00 4c 64 72 47  |0.0.1.5.....LdrG|
000007b0  65 74 50 72 6f 63 65 64  75 72 65 41 64 64 72 65  |etProcedureAddre|
000007c0  73 73 00 00 6e 74 64 6c  6c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ss..ntdll.......|
000007d0  20 69 6e 66 6c 61 74 65  20 31 2e 32 2e 33 20 43  | inflate 1.2.3 C|
000007e0  6f 70 79 72 69 67 68 74  20 31 39 39 35 2d 32 30  |opyright 1995-20|
000007f0  30 35 20 4d 61 72 6b 20  41 64 6c 65 72 20 00 00  |05 Mark Adler ..|
```

Am I missing something ? Or did they mask the `gzip` signature ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binwalk did not find the zlib blob because it is also encrypted. It uses the following code to decrypt the compressed data. The decryption uses a table stored in the stack, which is filled with generated values before the loop.

[image]

Thus, you have to reverse the decryption code or save the decompressed data from the memory.

Comment: could you recommend a tool to dump data from memory to file ?

Comment: Try [ProcDump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Reverse_Engineering/File_Formats for the following example:

```
inflate 1.1.3 Copyright 1995-1998 Mark Adler
```

> It is a good bet to assume that at least parts of the file are ZIP
>   compressed. Further probing might reveal that the file does not
>   contain a complete ZIP archive, but just a section which is compressed
>   with the ZIP deflate algorithm, and supposed to be decompressed with
>   the ZIP inflate algorithm (likely version 1.1.3, as the output of
>   strings revealed). Therefore, the fictitious file might be further
>   separated into its components by using a custom tool which iteratively
>   applies the inflate algorithm to the file, until the generated result
>   makes some sense (e.g. until the result contains some recognizable
>   clear text strings).

It seems to be the very same case for new, except that your inflate's version is 1.2.3